# `vim-plug` plugin does not work on Vim 9.0 on Windows

Tags: vim-plugin

I have already followed the steps here: [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug). 'vim-plug' plugin will work properly. When loading vim, I get the below:

```
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Here's my VIM RC:

```
" Specify a directory for plugins
" - For Neovim: ~/.local/share/nvim/plugged
" - Avoid using standard Vim directory names like 'plugin'
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
    " Basic
    Plug 'itchyny/lightline.vim'
    Plug 'tpope/vim-sensible'
" Initialize plugin system
call plug#end()

" Colorscheme
:set termguicolors
colorscheme wombat

" Line numbers
set number

" Tabs
filetype plugin indent on
" show existing tab with 4 spaces width
set tabstop=4
" when indenting with '>', use 4 spaces width
set shiftwidth=4
" On pressing tab, insert 4 spaces
set expandtab

" Folding
set foldmethod=indent
set foldlevel=99

" GUI gVim
if has('gui_running')
  if has('gui_win32')
    set guifont=Cascadia_Code_PL:h18:cANSI:qDRAFT
  endif
endif
```